# How can I reset or change rules for SonarLint in VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

Using SonarLint in VSCode, I disabled certain rules to get a local java program to run.  However when checked in to the GIT project, the CI build failed.  How can I turn the SonarLint rules back on so I can get the benefit of the linting again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open View > Command Palette...  (Mac: Cmd+Shift+P)

Select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

In the settings.json file, the disabled SonarLint rules are listed:

```
"sonarlint.rules": {
    "java:S2095": {
        "level": "off"
    },
    "java:S1192": {
        "level": "off"
    }
}
```

Delete the rules you wish to reactivate, save the settings

Comment: You may mark your answer for more people with similar questions to reach this solution:)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with C# (I tried `cs:`, `c#:`, `C#:`, `csharp:`)

Comment: The question is specific to java so given configurations json works.