# How configure SonarLint rules for C# code in VS?

Tags: c#, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I installed [SonarLint for Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.SonarLintforVisualStudio2022) and found the option to edit rule settings:
[image: Tools -> Options -> SonarLint]

This creates file `%appdata%\SonarLint for Visual Studio\settings.json` with following content:

```
"sonarlint.rules": { }
```

How can I suppress a rule here? A [sample for Java is given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66465439/2484903) but it does not work for C# and VS2022.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.editorconfig` to configure/suppress SonarLint rules. For example:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.S6602.severity = none
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for this.  This isn't mentioned at all in the [Disabling a rule](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarlint/visual-studio/using-sonarlint/rules/#disabling-a-rule) documentation, and the [settings.json file format and location](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarlint/visual-studio/using-sonarlint/rules/#settingsjson-file-format-and-location) section gives no clues or examples how to format what you need. This ".editorconfig" approach is potentially a better solution, as it allows the settings to be configured per repository rather than per user.